# ImageIcon will not display image

Tags: java, image, imageicon

I cannot display an image. I have tried both ImageIO and ImageIcon.

This is my code:

```
public TestGUImain()
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Basic Window");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    frame.add(panel);

    JLabel lblText = new JLabel("Hello World", JLabel.CENTER);
    lblText.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 200);
    panel.add(lblText);

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("150_leading_side_prep.jpg"));
    JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(image, JLabel.CENTER);
    lblImage.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
    panel.add(lblImage);
}
```

P.S. if the `JLabel` is changed to have text in it, it *will* display. The image is stored in a source folder called resource at the same level as the src folder.

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` would be your first mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the image in the src folder, not at the same level as it. You also need to do frame.setVisible(true) at the end of your constructor, or use `revalidate();` and `repaint();` to refresh your window.

Comment: After importing the image into the src folder, I get a null pointer error. I tried sticking a '/', 'src/' and '/src/' on the front of the path but to no avail..

Comment: @LewisDean Thanks for accepting the answer. You should read the whole post before commenting. And if my post helped you, please consider upvoting.

Comment: I did but it won't show for you until my reputation goes a bit higher, new account :) Also only the first sentence of your comment appeared for me, After I commented the page reloaded and the rest of your comment appeared. Maybe you edited it?

Comment: @LewisDean Oh, right I did. Well thanks for the upvote anyway.